# Entity Framework 6 how to update field based on old value without reload?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-6.1

I'm finding a way to implement the behavior below in sql:

```
update TableName set Column1 = Column1 + 2
```

Does new entity framework 6 supports this kind?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `ExecuteSqlCommand`

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"UPDATE TableName SET [Column1] = [Column1] + 2");
```

And ofcourse you may consider to make some wrapping method to make this generic if you'll use is in many tables

Comment: thanks, but I dislike raw sql within code. It will make me crazy when maintain. I'm looking for a solution supported by EF without raw sql.

Answer (score 0):

Not by default, but there is a NuGet package available that provides this feature.

https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

```
//update all tasks with status of 1 to status of 2
context.Tasks.Update(t => t.StatusId == 1, t2 => new Task {StatusId = 2});
```